# pydev on aptana3 unable to import gi.repository

Tags: aptana, pydev, gnome, gtk3, pygobject

the following code should work

```
import gi
import gi.repository
```

this works in a python shell. And it also works if I save the file as a script then launch it  in a terminal.
but in aptana3 i get this:

```
import gi.repository
ImportError: No module named repository
```

i think this [bug report](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3284889&group_id=85796&atid=577329) may have a clue

- Ubuntu Natty Gnome3 32Bit
- Pydev on python 2.7.1+
- System on python 2.7.1+

Answer (score 5):

Goto

```
window > preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - (Python/Jython/IronPython).
```

Goto `Forced Builtins` tab

Click on  `New`

add `gi`

Apply and then check.